# Extracting the grid coordinates in a raster map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, grids-graticules

I have a gridded raster map produced from the NASA precipitation data over a country. The pixel type of the map is in floating point with 32 Bit pixel depth. Therefore, it does not have any attribute table. Now I have two questions:

1. If I use the Int command in the ArcToolbox to convert the map to Integer point pixel type I lose lots of information of the gridded data. What is the solution to convert it to Integer point pixel type without losing so much information. The data are rainfall amount in 10km *10km grid points and the values are mainly different in regards to their decimal and removing that convert the map into just 4 categories!
2. In the original map with the floating point with 32 Bit pixel depth, how can I extract the 10km *10km coordinates? It is too many coordinates (above 15000 grids) and I need a solution to extract it. Converting to ASCII did not help, by the way.

Comment: Using gdal_translate you can convert the grid into ASCII XYZ GRID, you'll get XYZ coordinates of grid point in a row of the output file.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not familiar with the gdal_translate and coding and would like to know the same approach of gdal in ArcGIS 10.2 that I am using to prepare the maps.

Comment: You need not coding to use gdal_translate it is a ready to use program, see http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

Comment: How To: Convert a raster dataset to an XYZ table Summary

It is explained here @ http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000007693

Comment: What is it exactly that you want? Having the raster table and ability to compute coordinates are 2 different things. Please explain your objective and software you prefer to use.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  The tour states that there should be just one question per question, however you have asked multiple questions making this too broad.  Please [edit] your question to focus on just one specific question, and include more details about what you're trying to do, and what happens when you try it.  Be specific.  Include screenshots if that helps explain the problem.

Comment: @FelixIP I found a solution for the second question to extract the table of coordinates of a raster map. However, no solution yet for the question 1. I am using ArcGIS 10.2. I have a map with nearly 16000 grid points that each grid has a floating value. I want to make each grid to Integer value. When I do it, then all the values of the 16000 grids becomes just into 4 categories and I lose many information.. What to do?

Comment: Just convert raster to points and add geometry attributes. Two tools